# whereBetween passing a value and null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an eloquent query and I am passing a value and null in it. So for example if I have an price column and I have two variables `$to` and `$from`.

Example `$from = 10 $to= ""`

```
$from = 10;
$to = "";  
Product::whereBetween('price', [$from, $to])->get();
```

My question is that is this okay, will this work? If no then what shall I do if I want to search from `10` to *infinity*?

Comment: will you specify ,do you want 10 area record or just area like 10?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `??` in **php** for checking null values, so if the first value is empty, it will be equal the second value you've passed. like:

```
$from = $request->to ?? 0;
$to = $request->to ?? Model::max('column'); // names are imaginary
```

Answer (score 0):

if `$to` can be empty value you should check it and build different queries depends on it.
 **For example:**

```
$products = Product::query();

if(empty($to))
{
   $products = $products->where('price','>=', $from);
}
else 
{
   $products = $products->whereBetween('price', [$from, $to])
}

$products = $products->get();
```